# Grammar that numbers of letters `c` is greater than number of letters `b`

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Exactly as stated in the subject. I look for grammar which use letters $a, b ,c$ that numbers of letters $c$ is greater than number of letters $b$.

Example: $acbccba$ is generated by the grammar.

I thought about:

$S \rightarrow aS \mid bS \mid SCS$

$ C \rightarrow cb \mid ca$

but not sure if it works. Could you help me, please.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté I do not have 1000 rep in the other service. But thank you.

Comment: You can ask questions without offering a bounty, it's not mandatory...

Comment: So the grammar must contain all words with all combinations of a, b and c, that satisfy the "greater than" constraint?

Comment: @cyroxx Exacly.

Comment: Currently bounties are maxed out at 500 rep

Comment: **No need to offer `1000` RP** for this question, just wait for 5 mins..

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to advertise a bounty in the question title and body. Actually, I edited out these advertisements.

Comment: your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665058/grammar-that-contains-letters-a-b-c-and-number-of-letters-c-is-greater-than-nu) too

Answer (score 3):

Lowercase letters are terminals, uppercase nonterminals.

```
S → TcT

T → ε

T → aT
T → Ta

T → Tc
T → cT

T → bTc
T → cTb
```

The `S` rule ensures that there is at least one `c`. `T` then generates any string of `(abc)*` where every `b` is balanced by a `c`.

Comment: your grammar is simple and correct, I didn't notice first. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this grammar is correct. How do you produce "cbca" with it?

Comment: @svinja: you're right. I corrected it to generate S → cT → cTa → cbTca → cbca.

Comment: The solution alone is not very helpful. How did you get there? How can the OP solve similar problems?

Answer (score 3):

Your grammar never accepts a word since you can't make the $S$ disappear.

If you want to create more $c$ than $b$ you just have to make sure that when you create a $b$ you create a $c$ with it (but be careful they don't need to be side to side). You can also generate as much $a$ or $c$ as you want.

If you need more indication please ask.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for the edit. I should have read again before posting ;)

Answer (score 2):

The correct grammar is:

```
C -> ScS //starting from C
S -> SaS | ScS | ScSbS | SbScS | ε
```

Comment: `s --> SaS --> εaε --> a` in string `a`, `numbersof(b) == numberof(c)==0` , your grammar is wrong according to language, there is many other cases

Comment: An infinite number of them, in fact, since a* is a subset of this grammar's language.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan forgot to rewrite upper line from the paper. Now it is corrected.

Comment: The solution alone is not very helpful. How did you get there? How can the OP solve similar problems? (By the way, "the" correct grammar is not unique.)

Comment: @Raphael I think the solution is quite simple, it start with some (or at-least one) `c`, (start variable is `C`), then via `S` always insert either `a`, `c`, but whenever `b` is added a `c` is also added...Its good solution

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add a **`b`** also add a **`c`** and add some(atleat one extra **`c`**) whereas on **`a`** language do not impose any constraint so feel free a add **`a`** any numbers of time (even `0`), any where in language string. A Context Free Grammar is possible for your language.

```
S  --> cS | Sc | T

T  -->  ABC | BAC | BCA | ACB | CAB | CBA 

C  -->  cC  | c    

B  -->  b   | ^

A  -->  aA  | ^
```

**Edit:**

your grammar is not correct, because you can generate a string in which **`b`**s are more then **`c`**s, e.g:

your grammar:

```
S --> aS | bS |SCS    
C --> cb | ca
```

produces `bbacb` ad follows:

```
S --> bS --> bbS --> bbaS --> bbacb
```

Comment: This produces `ab` by `S --> ABC --> aBC --> abC --> ab`.

Comment: @larsmans ok...

Comment: I think you swapped `b` and `c`.

Comment: @larsmans yes that why I confusing while re-writing for your fist comment Thanks

Comment: I think this new version is correct (and maybe more easy to grasp than mine, so +1). I don't think you even need the `S` rules.

Comment: @larsmans I think yes, to save from equal numbers of **`C`** and **`b`**, as you commented

Comment: @larsmans Can I improve my grammar by remove `S` rules and change `C` rules like:  `C  -->  cC  | cc` ?

Comment: No need for a changed C. S only generates a B when it also produces a C, and it can never generate the empty string.

Answer (score -2):

$S \rightarrow SbS \mid bSS \mid SSb \mid b \mid bX \mid Xb$

$X \rightarrow bB \mid cA$

$A \rightarrow cX \mid cAA \mid b$

$B \rightarrow cX \mid bBB \mid b$

Comment: If I understand your notation here, you have a rule $S \rightarrow b$, and $S$ is the start symbol. This would allow the derivation of the string $b$, which is certainly not in the language. As a general note, this sort of answer is not really what this site is aiming to attract, try to make it clear, include explanations and put some effort into the formatting. Think of it like you're producing a (very short) lesson on the topic. I'll render your answer in TeX markup, take a look at it to see how to do it.